# Proof that a set is open using closed points on a $k$-scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $S \subset X$, where $X$ is an affine scheme of finite type over $k$ and $S(k)$ is not empty.

Let us suppose that the set of points of $S(k)$ is inside of the interior $\text{int } S$, that is, whenever $x \in S(k)$ there exists $f \in \mathcal{O}(X)$ such that $x \in X_f \subset S$.

Using this, I want to prove that the set $S$ is open.

Of course if $p \in S$ is not closed in $X$, but there is a closed point $x \in S(k)$ such that $x \in \overline{\{p\}}$, arguing using the corresponding ideals is enough to prove that $p \in \text{int } S$.

I removed this discussion from the context because I believe that this should be enough to prove the statement. If anyone has a counterexample, maybe I should restrict my hypothesis to get this.

EDIT: As pointed out, maybe the lack of context is making this harder. I am following Victoria Hoskins's notes on Geometric Invariant Theory ( https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/hoskins/M15_Lecture_notes.pdf ). At Proposition 4.36, she proves that the set of stable points of an action of a reductive group on an affine scheme $X$ (of finite type over $k$) is an open set using this argument.

Comment: This is trivially false: take $S$ to consist of the generic point of $\Bbb A^1_k$, for instance. You need more assumptions.

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I forgot to mention that the set $S$ contains at least one closed point! Editing this now.

Comment: That's still not enough: take $D(x)\cup \{(x)\}\subset \Bbb A^2_k$. See, part of the reason that context is good for problems like this is that users can help you figure out what assumption you really want here - "$S$ is a subset of an affine scheme of finite type over a field" is a very uncommon and very weak assumption. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: I should also add that it's not clear on what you're really assuming - your question and the answer you've accepted don't agree (the answer talks about closed points of $S$, while your question appears to talk about points of $S$ that are closed as points of $X$, and these are not the same).

Comment: Oh, I agree. I was confused with this difference, but I agree that my question is about closed points of X inside $S$, as the notation suggests. I included the reference of my exact question in here, to try to clarify this a bit.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean a closed point $x\in S(k)$? we don't know yet if $S$ is the underlying topological space of a scheme or not so $S(k)$ is meaningless. if you really mean that $S$ is a subsheme of $X$ and you only put the condition of $S(K)$ then as people said in the comments this is false.

but if you really mean for any closed point of $S$ then this is true because consider $U=interior\, of \,S$ then $Z=S-U$ is closed inside $S$. now take any maximal point $t$ of $Z$ (which exists by finiteness condition). then $t=\bar{\{t\}}\cap Z$ so $t$ is closed in $S$ but it is not in $U$ which is a contradiction.